# PHP: Double quoted link changing quotes

Tags: php, string, wordpress, parsing, shortcode

I'm having a problem that doesn't make any sense. **Why is my html being parsed incorrectly? Simply changing the way it's assigned in PHP seems to fix it, is it a PHP/Browser bug?**

When my shortcode looks like this:

> [gallerybl image='http://dev.netcoding.net/aristocrat-v2/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Mirage-Yellow-Birch-Montana11.jpg' href="#" title='Living Space']Epediti solore, solorep rectota il eat receriandia seque non pa ititissi solestenit omnimeture, sus sonata corpore rcimoll enissequi custiam.[/gallerybl]

WordPress (using everything as default, I turned every filter off), calls the below function and `$image1` is parsed incorrectly as (notice the first quote in the `a` tag):

```
<a href="#' title='Living Space'><span class='gallery_bl_img'><img src='http://dev.netcoding.net/aristocrat-v2/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Mirage-Yellow-Birch-Montana11.jpg"  alt='Living Space' /></span></a>
```

---

Here is the function being called:

```
function get_gallery_block( $atts, $content = "" ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'image' => '',
        'href' => '',
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    $image  = "<span class='gallery_bl_img'><img src='{$image}' alt='{$title}' /></span>";
    $image1 = empty( $href )    ? $image : "<a href='{$href}' title='{$title}'>{$image}</a>";
    $image2 = empty( $href )    ? $image : '<a href="' . $href . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $image . "</a>";
    $htitle = empty( $title )   ? ""     : "<span class='gallery_bl_title'>{$title}</span>";
    $clink  = empty( $content ) ? ""     : ( empty( $href ) ? "" : "<a href='#' title='{$title}'>READ MORE</a>" );
    $desc   = empty( $content ) ? ""     : "<span class='gallery_bl_content'>{$content} {$clink}</span>";

    $format = ( $htitle . $image1 . $desc );
    return "<div class='gallery_bl_container'>{$format}</div>";

}
add_shortcode( 'gallerybl', 'get_gallery_block' );
```

Browser: `Google Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m`, if that helps.

PHP Version: 5.4.24 (CGI/FastCGI)

Comment: what's more buggy: PHP, your browser or wordpress?

Comment: I have the latest of all 3 versions, unmodofied. (PHP latest as available from my host)

Comment: Could it possibly be that you are mixing quotes when calling the shortcode? Wordpress' shortcode parser is stupidly complex so try not to confuse it. Stick with the same quotes for all attributes

Comment: Using the same quotes in the shortcode has no output change, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, your use of the ternary operator is just silly (and possibly incorrect with the nested one).

Comment: Changing it to a regular conditional to see if `$href` is not empty does not fix the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole thing needs a clean-up (mostly for readability). Try this...

```
add_shortcode('gallerybl', function($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'image' => null,
        'href'  => null,
        'title' => null
    ), $atts));

    // escape all atts for HTML
    $image = htmlspecialchars($image);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $href = htmlspecialchars($href);

    $imgMarkup = sprintf('<span class="gallery_bl_img"><img src="%s" alt="%s"></span>',
        $image, $title);
    if ($href) {
        $imgMarkup = sprintf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>',
            $href, $title, $imgMarkup);
    }

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="gallery_bl_container">
        <?php if ($title) : ?>
            <span class="gallery_bl_title"><?= $title ?></span>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?= $imgMarkup ?>
        <?php if ($content) : ?>
            <span class="gallery_bl_content">
                <?= do_shortcode($content) ?>
                <?php if ($href) : ?>
                    <a href="#" title="<?= $title ?>">READ MORE</a>
                <?php endif ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

Comment: This works. Could you explain why using single quotes in shortcode output breaks? That's the main problem I'm having here.

Comment: Yes your code does work, but why is mine breaking? It looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @BrianGraham Well, apart from having an unused variable `($image2)` and overwriting the `$image` attribute, you are using nested ternary statements which hardly ever work how you think they do. See http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#example-124

Comment: Eh I don't really care anymore, I'll accept this as an answer since it does get around the problem.